# How to connect two Client IP to the same mongodb using c++ Drivers

Tags: c++, mongodb, nginx, ip

I am trying to make a client with mongo c++ drivers to connect to the database. I successfully tested the client for the localhost.The code I used for that is below.

Now I want to have the database and clients on different machines for example client on IP 10.1.2.56 and the mongodb on IP 10.1.2.57

I changes should I make in the code to achieve that. I tried to change the line

```
c.connect("localhost"); //"192.168.58.1");
```

To

```
 c.connect("10.1.2.57"); //"192.168.58.1");
```

But that does not work
The error says "caught can't connect to server 10.1.2.57:27017 " I tried to ping the IP 10.1.2.57 and it give me the response also .

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

// g++ src/mongo/client/examples/tutorial.cpp -pthread -Isrc -Isrc/mongo -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -L[path to libmongoclient.a] -o tutorial
//g++ tutorial.cpp -L[mongo directory] -L/opt/local/lib -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -I/opt/local/include  -o tutorial

using namespace mongo;

void printIfAge(DBClientConnection& c, int age) {
    auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("tutorial.persons", QUERY( "age" << age ).sort("name") );
    while( cursor->more() ) {
        BSONObj p = cursor->next();
        cout << p.getStringField("name") << endl;
    }
}

void run() {
    DBClientConnection c;
    c.connect("localhost"); //"192.168.58.1");
    cout << "connected ok" << endl;
    BSONObj p = BSON( "name" << "Joe" << "age" << 33 );
    c.insert("tutorial.persons", p);
    p = BSON( "name" << "Jane" << "age" << 40 );
    c.insert("tutorial.persons", p);
    p = BSON( "name" << "Abe" << "age" << 33 );
    c.insert("tutorial.persons", p);
    p = BSON( "name" << "Methuselah" << "age" << BSONNULL);
    c.insert("tutorial.persons", p);
    p = BSON( "name" << "Samantha" << "age" << 21 << "city" << "Los Angeles" << "state" << "CA" );
    c.insert("tutorial.persons", p);

    c.ensureIndex("tutorial.persons", fromjson("{age:1}"));

    cout << "count:" << c.count("tutorial.persons") << endl;

    auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("tutorial.persons", BSONObj());
    while( cursor->more() ) {
        cout << cursor->next().toString() << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nprintifage:\n";
    printIfAge(c, 33);
}

int main() {
    try {
        run();
    }
    catch( DBException &e ) {
        cout << "caught " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the `connect` call return any kind of error code? Is there a firewall in the way that stops things? What does the logs on the server say? Please elaborate _how_ it "does not work".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The error says "caught can't connect to server 10.1.2.57:27017 " I tried to ping the IP 10.1.2.57 and it give me the response also .

Comment: While I'm not experienced in MongoDB, I'm certain that the exception probably have some more information that can be used, e.g. the actual error.

Comment: Try to print the return of `toString()` of the exception, and see what that says. Or try to catch a [`SocketException`](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.3.0/classmongo_1_1_d_b_exception.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer of the above question

Earlier the mongod was running on the defined port and path on the Mongodb server side

So I stoped the Mongodb by following command

```
$ sudo stop mongodb
```

and once again started the server with the default defined path by the following command

```
$ sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db --port 27017
```

and then tried the above code in c++ and this time it connected to the remote server.